# Would including a line like "source ~/rc/.zshrc" in my ~/.zshrc be equivelent to including all the text from ~/rc/.zshrc in my ~/.zshrc?

Tags: zsh, macos, rc

I want to keep my `~/.zshrc` in a github repo, and since I don't want to make my ~ folder a git repository, I plan to move my `~/.zshrc` to a folder called `rc` and then include `source ./rc/.zshrc` in my `~/.zshrc` file.

I'm wondering if there's any reason to keep everything within the actual `~/.zshrc` file instead of moving it to `~/rc/.zshrc`

---

I use an Intel mac, could possibly use the `.zshrc` on a cloud server with ubuntu, and will probably get a mac with an M chip in the next few years if that's relevant

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if there's any reason to keep everything within the actual `~/.zshrc` file instead of moving it to `~/rc/.zshrc`.

No, there's no need.

And there are other options as well:

- Make `~/.zshrc` a link to `~/rc/.zshrc`.
- Put `ZDOTDIR=~/rc` in `~/.zshenv`. Then all other [zsh initialization files](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files-2) like `.zprofile`, `.zshrc`, `.zlogin`, etc. will read from `~/.rc`.